# "Если чем..."

Tags: грамотная-речь

Имеется такое предложение: "Однако новопостроенный аэропорт, если и превосходит старый, так это своей колоссальной стоимостью..."
Корректор между "если" и "и" вставил "чем", то есть, "если чем и превосходит...". А допустим ли изначальный вариант - без "чем"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет, корректор прав, опускать "чем" здесь никак нельзя.
Без "чем" фраза грамматически (или, может, синтаксически) неправильна или несёт другой смысл.

Если чем (и) [делает]..., то [тем-то]
и 
Если (и) [делает]..., то [то-то]

это совершенно разные по смыслу конструкции.

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, перед *если* не нужна запятая. Во-вторых, фраза красивее звучала бы так: *Однако новопостроенный аэропорт если и превосходит старый, так **только** своей колоссальной стоимостью..."*  В-третьих, в предложенном Amarie варианте, конечно, лучше так, как исправил корректор.

Comment: *~~~Во-первых, перед если не нужна запятая.*  
Да, конечно.  
*~~~Во-вторых, фраза красивее звучала бы так...*  
А вот тут - не уверен. Без чем все равно плохо, ибо сходу непонятно.